# Add CSS to whitelist - border-radius, opacity, text-shadow

Tags: htmlpurifier

Starting off, I have very little understanding of the PHP or how HTMLPurifier itself works and am completely learning on the go. I've got a fair understanding of HTML and CSS from teaching myself, but I wouldn't call myself anything more than a novice at this point.

I run a myBB forum via hostgator wherein my users want HTML allowed to make fancy tables for their posts. Since we only opened shop a month ago and have a very small userbase so far of people I know and trust, I enabled HTML. About a week ago I used a plugin plus the current library to install HTMLPurifier into my forum. It works great. Thing is, it eats up a majority of the code my users are using to make their posts look good.

I tried to plug this code which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17496613/htmlpurifier-with-borderradius) into my CSSDefinition.php file between the border-color and border-width codes to try to fix the border-radius issue.

```
// border-radius
$border_radius =
    $this->info['border-top-left-radius'] =
    $this->info['border-top-right-radius'] =
    $this->info['border-bottom-left-radius'] =
    $this->info['border-bottom-right-radius'] = new HTMLPurifier_AttrDef_CSS_Composite(array
(
    new HTMLPurifier_AttrDef_CSS_Length('0'),
    new HTMLPurifier_AttrDef_CSS_Percentage(true)
)
);
    $this->info['border-radius'] = new HTMLPurifier_AttrDef_CSS_Multiple($border_radius);
```

That did absolutely nothing, I assume because his is out of date. I haven't been able to find any information on adding text-shadow to my whitelist, nor how to allow opacity, either through  `opacity:#;` or `rbga(#,#,#,0.5)`, though I did find a hack for the latter that I couldn't make heads or tails of for what to actually do with the file.

I don't know how to run my Config.php file because looking at the code I can see there is information there, but trying to visit the page through various means gets me nowhere.

Comment: I advise you to read the "Configuration Documentation" here: http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html. HTMLPurifier works with a white list. By default every HTML tag and attributes are blacklisted. So you should use a white list to only allow certain HTML and CSS attributes/properties.

Comment: I understand that. If you read my post, you would see that I'm asking for assistance in how to whitelist three specific CSS elements, two of which I have no idea the codes I should insert. I've looked through that "Configuration Documentation" document and found where it talks about CSS.AllowedProperties but that does not appear to be working when I try to add the border-radius code that I linked above.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @user706420 I have not found a solution. I've been trying to make do with using the profanity filter for some coding that has caused minor issues (nothing malicious) but I really would like to be able to use HTMLPurifier.

Comment: A patch for border radius you can found here:
https://github.com/ezyang/htmlpurifier/pull/19

A patch for rgba you can found here:
https://reviews.mahara.org/#/c/3679/2/htdocs/lib/htmlpurifier/HTMLPurifier/AttrDef/CSS/Color.php

opacity is included, you must use 
$config->set('CSS.AllowTricky', TRUE);

don't forget to delete the css cache in htmlpurifer

i still search a solution for text- and border-shadow. ;)

Comment: @user706420 Thank you! I was looking to try to clear the cache and didn't find a folder called CSS within DefinitionCache\Serializer\ . The Serializer folder is empty apart from a dummy README file. 

edit: When I installed HTMLPurifier to my mybb forum, I only included the /library folder, as instructed by the plugin I used to set it up, and I noticed that 'flush.php' is of course outside of that. Is that the only way to clear the cache?

Comment: @user706420 Have you seen any whitelist codes for the overflow:scroll/hidden/etc code? The fixes you showed me for the other portions worked.